# how do you get String Tokenizer to ignore text?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have this code:

```
public void readTroops() {
        File file = new File("resources/objects/troops.txt");
    StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String text = null;

        // repeat until all lines is read
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer troops = new StringTokenizer(text,"=");
            String list = troops.nextToken();
            String value = troops.nextToken();
}
```

and this file:

```
//this is a comment part of the text file//

Total=1
```

the problem is that 1) I cant get it to ignore everything within the //,// and can't get it to read with an 'ENTER' (line) in-between them. For example, this text works:

```
Total=1
```

So my question is what do I type into the delimiter area ie.

```
StringTokenizer troops = new StringTokenizer(text,"=","WHAT GOES HERE?");
```

So how can I get Tokenizer to ignore 'ENTER'/new line, and anything in-between // or something similar, thanks.

ps.I don't care if you use a String.split to answer my question.

Comment: are you parsing a properties file (name=value pairs with maybe comments?)

Comment: its a txt file, not a properties file (is a properties file a file type?) and not a rtf or rtfd...

Comment: yes, txt file, with name=value lines and optionally comments?

Comment: if that's the case you'd use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: for api 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `countTokens` to skip lines that don't have two tokens:

```
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        StringTokenizer troops = new StringTokenizer(text,"="); 
        if(troops.countTokens() == 2){
            String list = troops.nextToken(); 
            String value = troops.nextToken(); 
            ....
        }else { 
            //ignore this line
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("properties_file.txt"));
assertExuals("1",prop.getProperty("Total"));
```

ps. you  might hold and close input stream.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking out of the box, maybe you can use `Properties` instead of tokenizer (if you update your comments to start with `#`)?

```
Properties troops = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("troops.properties");
try {
    props.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle error
} finally {
    // Close inputStream in a safe manner
}
troops.getProperty("Total"); // Returns "1"
```

Or if you are using Java 7:

```
Properties troops = new Properties();
try (InputStream inputStream = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("troops.properties")) {
    props.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle error
}
troops.getProperty("Total"); // Returns "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading in the file a better way would be to use a **StreamTokenizer**. This then allows you to declare your own syntax of the tokenizer. I used this method to create a HTML rendering engine. This then allows you to parse direct from a reader, and also provides useful functions to identify numbers, which it seems you may use.
(I will post an example once my eclipse loads!)

```
public static String render(String file, HashMap vars){

    // Create a stringbuffer to rebuild the string
    StringBuffer renderedFile = new StringBuffer();
    try{
    FileReader in = new FileReader(file); 
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in); // create your reader
    StreamTokenizer tok;
        tok = new StreamTokenizer(reader); //the tokenizer then takes in the reader as a builder
        tok.resetSyntax();
        tok.wordChars(0, 255); //sets all chars (inc spaces to be counted as words)
        /*
         *  quoteChar allows you to set your comment char, for example $ hello $ means it will ignore hello 
         */
        tok.quoteChar('$'); 

    while(tok.nextToken()!=StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){ //while it is not at the end of file
    String s = tok.sval;
    if (vars.containsKey(s))
        s =(String)vars.get(s); 
    renderedFile.append(s);
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error Loading Template");}

    return renderedFile.toString();

}
```

Check this out for a good tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/streamtokenizer.html